# ROUGE-SU metric, Meaning and formula

Tags: text, nlp, text-mining, evaluation, summarization

From the wikipedia the definition of the ROUGE-SU metric is the following:

**ROUGE-SU: Skip-bigram plus unigram-based co-occurrence statistics.**

My question is the following what is the precise formula of this metric and what is the intuition behind the ROUGE-SU metric?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you might also want to have a look at these slides from ROUGE's author:http://users.dsic.upv.es/~dpinto/duc/RougeLin.pdf

Answer (score 2):

The **S** means skip bigram. It means to match 2 non contiguous words (i.e. with other words between) which allows rephrasing and sentence reorganization. As ROUGE score is supposed to evaluate automatic summaries, its a good point.

The **U** means unigram, i.e. 1-grams, = counting common words

Thus **SU** means that we count both skip-bigram **and** unigram. The point is to make a *soft* skip bigram in that, we may not want to assign a 0 score to a sentence just because it does not share a skip bigram when it instead has common unigram.

Did you got the point?

Anyway, note that no ROUGE score is perfect by itself. You always should get several values which shows different characteristics.

Hope this helps
`pltrdy`
As a side note, I developped a script to compute ROUGE scores between 2 files. Find it here: https://github.com/pltrdy/files2rouge